# Classifying Multivariate Time Series

Tags: time, classification, series

I currently am working on a time series witch 430 attributes and approx. 80k instances. Now I would like to binary classify each instance (not the whole ts). Everything I found about classifying TS talked about labeling the whole thing.
Is it possible to classify each instance with something like a SVM completely disregarding the sequential nature of the data or would that only result in a really bad classifier? 
Which other options are there which classify each instance but still look at the data as a time series?

Comment: Are asking for other classifiers for your data....

Answer (score 2):

If the data is labeled, you may have luck by concatenating attributes together, so each instance becomes a single long time series, and by applying the so-called [Shapelet Transform](https://www.uea.ac.uk/~ajb/Papers/HillsDAMI2013.pdf). This would result in a vector of values for each of time series which can be fed into SVM, Random Forest, or any other classifier. It could be that picking a right shapelets will allow you to focus on a single attribute when classifying instances.

If it is not labeled, you may try the [unsupervised shapelets](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jzaka001/pdf/ClusteringTimeSeriesUsingUnsupervised-Shapelets.pdf) application first to explore your data and proceed with aforementioned shapelet transform after.

Comment: thanks for the linkt to the shapelet transform paper.

Comment: @seninp I just stumbled across your answer.  Out of curiosity, do you think it would be possible to apply a shapelet transform to panel/cross sectional time series data?  In the literature, I usually only see it applied to time series of real values.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly depends on the data within the 430 attributes, 
data types, and **especially the problem you want to solve**.

In time series analysis, you usually want to exploit the dependencies between the neighboring points, i.e., how they change in time. The examples you may find in books usually talk about a single function `f(t): Time -> Real`. If I understand it correctly, you want to focus just on the dependencies among the 430 attributes (vertical dependencies) and disregard the horizontal dependencies.

If I were you, I would first try to train multiple classifiers (SVM, Maximum entropy model, Multi-layer perceptron, Random forest, Probabilistic Neural Network, ...) and compare their prediction performance in the frame of your problem.

For training, you can start by feeding all 430 attributes as features to Maxent classifier (can easily handle millions of features).
You also need to perform some N-fold cross-validation to see whether the classifiers are not overfitted. Then pick the best that solves your problem "good enough".

Other ideas if this approach does not perform well:

- include features from t-1, t-2...
- perform feature selection by trying different subsets of features
- derive new time series such as moving averages, wavelet spectrum ... and use them as new features

A nice implementation of Maxent classifier can be found in [openNLP](http://maxent.sourceforge.net/about.html).